# Combining two columns in a set following Pandas groupby operation

Tags: python, pandas, set, pandas-groupby

Say I have a dataframe

```
         Date   A   B
0  2019-05-02  12  23
1  2019-05-02  23  13
2  2019-05-02  12  13
3  2019-05-03  12  13
```

If I wanted to groupby the date and apply set on the column A, I can do it by

```
A_df = test_df.groupby(['Date'])['A'].apply(set)
```

giving the result

```
Date
2019-05-02    {12, 23}
2019-05-03        {12}
```

Similarly, I can do it for B.

```
B_df = test_df.groupby(['Date'])['B'].apply(set)
```

which gives the result.

```
Date
2019-05-02    {13, 23}
2019-05-03        {13}
```

How do I create one whereby the set is created from both the contents of both columns A and B? The desired output can be thought of as a union of the outputs above.

```
Date
2019-05-02    {12, 13, 23}
2019-05-03        {12, 13}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [`stack()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and then do the `groupby()`:

```
df.set_index('Date').stack().reset_index(0,name='AB').groupby('Date')['AB'].apply(set)
#Alternate sol with itertools
#df.groupby('Date').apply(lambda x: set(itertools.chain.from_iterable(x[['A','B']].values)))
```

---

```
 Date
2019-05-02    {12, 13, 23}
2019-05-03        {12, 13}
Name: AB, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great answers. I prefer the lambda approach as it seems to contain fewer manipulations.

Answer (score 2):

Try the below code, Hope this will help:

```
dic = {}
for date in set(test_df['Date']):
    dic[date] = set(A_df.get_group(date)['A']).union(set(A_df.get_group(date)['B']))
```

Ouput will be :

```
{'2019-05-02': {12, 13, 23}, '2019-05-03': {12, 13}}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways to `flatten` a matrix, such as `stack`, `melt` or just `flatten` with numpy array.

```
df.set_index('Date').groupby('Date').apply(lambda x:set(x.values.flatten()))

df.set_index('Date').groupby('Date').apply(lambda x:set(x.stack()))
```